# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen »nach« und »in«?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference

> Ich beginne **nach** drei Monaten mit dem Studium.
>   Ich beginne **in** drei Monaten mit dem Studium.

Bedeuten die zwei Sätze das Gleiche?
Oder bedeutet das Wort „in“ „innerhalb“?

Comment: "ich habe vor 2 Monaten ausgesetzt. In einem Monat beginne ich nach 3 Monaten wieder mit dem Studium". 'in' zeigt den Bezug auf jetzt, 'nach' den Bezug auf einen anderen Zeitpunkt

Answer (score 2):

Wie Janka schon geantwortet hat, wird der Unterschied klarer, wenn wir den zeitlichen Rahmen vorgeben.
Und wenn wir den Referenzzeitpunkt etwas hin und her schieben, ergeben sich noch mehr Varianten:

*a) Heute:*

Ich beginne heute mit dem Umbau meines Hauses.
**Nach** 3 Monaten will ich mit den Wänden und Böden fertig sein.
**In** 2 Monaten werde ich mehr Helfer für die Elektroarbeiten bekommen.

Hier sind **in** und **nach** gleichwertig verwendbar. Beide bezeichnen einen Zeitpunkt, der in der Zukunft liegt und von heute aus gemessen wird.

Die beiden Zeitpunkte sind *heute+3 Monate* bzw. *heute + 2 Monate*

*b) Vergangenheit:*

Letzten Herbst habe ich mein Studium begonnen.
Schon **nach** 3 Monaten hatte ich Probleme, den Stoff zu verstehen.
**In** 2 Wochen muss ich eine Semesterarbeit abgeben.

In diesem Fall bezieht sich **nach** auf eine Zeit nach Start des Studiums und die 3 Monate sind bereits vorbei. Im Gegensatz dazu ist der Startzeitpunkt für **in** wiederum der heutige Tag.

Die beiden Zeitpunkte sind *letzter Herbst+3 Monate* bzw. *heute + 2 Wochen*

*c) Zukunft:*

**In** 2 Monaten will ich meine Weltreise beginnen. **Nach** 3 Wochen erreichen wir den Atlantik, den wir **in** 14 Tagen überqueren wollen.

Hier liegen zwar alle Termine in der Zukunft, aber der erste davon bezieht sich auf den aktuellen Zeitpunkt, während der zweite vom ersten Zeitpunkt aus gerechnet wird. Die dritte Zeitangebe hingegen ist anders als bei der ersten Verwendung von **in** kein Zeitpunkt, sondern eine Zeitspanne. Hier könntest du auch **innerhalb** verwenden.

Die Zeitpunkte sind *heute + 2 Monate* für die Abreise, *heute + 2 Monate + 3 Wochen* für das Erreichen der Küste und *heute + 2 Monate + 5 Wochen*

Answer (score 1):

Mit Zeiten benutzt, deutet **nach** eine Abfolge oder Lücke an. Wenn man einen zeitlichen Rahmen vorgibt, wird es deutlich:

> Ich habe mich bei einem Programm für ausländische Studenten angemeldet.
>
> Ich beginne **nach** drei Monaten mit dem (eigentlichen) Studium.
>
> **Bis dahin** mache ich einen Deutsch-Intensivkurs.

Der Satz mit *bis dahin* füllt die Lücke. Dadurch wird es eine Abfolge.

Man kann den mittleren Satz auch mit **in** bilden, allerdings kriegt der Zuhörer dann nichts davon mit, dass noch etwas anderes zu diesem Studentenprogramm gehört:

> Ich beginne **in** drei Monaten mit dem Studium.